How to get news in SPFx-React through SharePoint online? Is it possible to show SharePoint online news web part in my SPFx-React in div section?
How to get news in SPFx-React through SharePoint online? Is it possible to show SharePoint online news web part in my SPFx-React in div section?
Current code:
 <div className="lowercard">
          <div
            className="row QuikLinksrow"
            style={{
              margin: "0px",
            }}
          >
            <h5 className="rowheading">News</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="DocumentColumn">
            {Event.map((item: any) => {
              console.log(item);
              return (
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-body" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                      <div className="col-lg-4 imagecontainer">
                        {/* <img
                          src={
                            item.Attachments
                              ? item.Attachments
                              : require("../assets/peakpx.jpg")
                          }
                          className="card-img-top"
                          alt="..."
                        /> */}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-lg-8 contentcol">
                        <div className="card-content">
                          <div className="row">
                            <h5
                              className="card-title"
                              style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                            >
                              {item.Title.length > 25
                                ? `${item.Title.slice(0, 25)}...`
                                : item.Title}
                            </h5>
                          </div>
                          <div className="row">
                            <h6 className="card-subtitle">
                              {item.Description}
                            </h6>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>

